# How does time in the blockchain work?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, timestamp

I hope this question is not bad one, but this has been something I have been having trouble understanding.  How does time in the blockchain work, and how can I utilize variables like `block.timestamp` and the like? **I am creating a faucet where the user can withdraw a set amount of ether, then they have to wait one hour before they can withdraw more.**

Edit for duplication:  I have looked at other explanations here on StackExchange, but it did not answer my question.  I would like to know how time is passed on the blockchain, and with this knowledge utilize block.timestamp. I apologize if I was unclear.  I am a beginner with creating Dapps, and want to learn! :)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks  I am creating a faucet where the user can withdraw a set amount of ether, then they have to wait one hour before they can withdraw more. This is not calling the contract at a later time, but making the withdraw function unavailable to the address for one hour.

Comment: Okay - reading the description again, and your comment, I was perhaps a bit hasty. I've retracted my suggested dupe :-)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Now worries! I think I was a bit unclear in asking. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `block.timestamp` should indicate approximately when the block was mined. But it is only an approximation, it depends on the precision of the clock of the machines working on it, also a miner can modify it. So it is not a very secure measure of the time but for your use case should be good.

From [solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#time-units)

> block.timestamp (uint): current block timestamp as seconds since unix epoch.

You can do something like this:

```
mapping(address => uint) startTime;

function start() {
    startTime[msg.sender] = now;
}

function hasElapsed() constant return (bool) {
    if (now >= startTime[msg.sender] + 60 minutes) {
        // 60 minutes has elapsed from startTime[msg.sender]
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is what I have been trying to do! Let me make sure I have this right: you are mapping the `msg.sender` to the current block (a uint), then checking to see if the current block is more than or equal to the `msg.sender`'s time of transaction + 60 minutes, and finally doing whatever you need to do in the `if` function.

Comment: Actually, wouldn't be `if (now <= startTime[msg.sender] + 60 minutes)` with an less than equal to operator? So we can check as long as `now` is less or equal to `now` + 60 minutes?

Comment: In my example `startTime[msg.sender]` is the time where the watch has started, ie the user first request to the contract. Then `startTime[msg.sender] + 60 minutes` is 1 hour after the first request. In that case if `now <= startTime[msg.sender] + 60 minutes` is true, it implies that less than an hour has elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, per User will be difficult to enforce, as Ethereum only has Accounts, not Users. What's to prevent me from opening a dozen accounts and calling your Faucet at once?

Per Account, the answer above should work. My only concern would be the startTime mapping table, as being stateful, if the faucet is popular, how much gas would it consume on the mainnet?

Comment: I see your point, but this will the deployed for test ether (for now). I guess it will consume same gas on the testnet as well.