# How do we use block.number (as opposed to block.timestamp) for measuring time?

Tags: solidity, security

I've heard `block.timestamp` can be manipulated by miners, and as I am writing a contract that uses `block.timestamp` in crucial functions, I am wondering how best to mirror its behavior using block.number

Answer (score 4):

The timestamp can be [manipulated to a small degree](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21755/how-does-time-in-the-blockchain-work?rq=1) (unless a majority of miners are colluding, in which case all bets are off) since overtly abnormal timestamps will be rejected by other mining nodes.

`block.number` is presently a very unreliable method of measuring time (even for medium-term applications). Firstly, the time between blocks [is already changing regularly](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18576/how-time-difference-can-be-calculated-by-block-number-and-how-it-is-different-fr?rq=1) due to the difficulty bomb. Then, there is the proposed [delay of the difficulty bomb](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/649) -- which means you have to figure out whether it will happen. Then there's a potential for a change in block time at some other point in the future -- and all bets are off when we have proof of stake. So not only would I not recommend using `block.number` for counting time for medium- and long-term periods, it is not really possible, unless you can predict the future.

For short-term intervals (and before integral steps in difficulty change from the difficulty bomb are accounted for), you can use the average time for a block to be mined and multiply to create a time measurement. Approximate time elapsed is average time multiplied by block time.

Comment: That makes sense - but I think timestamp could matter a lot in my application. I have a betting pool essentially that, if someone bet and then submitted a block immediately after, could shut out other bets and win a portion of the pool. What I'm trying to get at is that the timestamp may be manipulatable by a small degree, but it could be pretty important for my application.

Comment: If you're trying to do something like betting on some event at a particular time, the average block time calculation will be less accurate than the timestamp. Even changing difficulty will cause problems -- and variance will cause more issues by itself in a single block than timestamp drift from attack.